# Time count and session variable for 4 hours long time

Tags: asp.net, session-variables, countdowntimer

I'm working on a ASP.NET Web Application which will allow conducting examinations and examination would be 4 hours long so worried to store the time count and answers selected for such a long time.

1. Should I use client side or server side timer (count down timer)?
2. Is it fine to store selected answers in Session variable?

Any input will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you must be used server side timer. because client side may be lost sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the Session Timeout to 4 hours will allow the user to enter information on a page and not have to log in when posting back within 4 hours.

If this is a rule i.e. if the user tries to save after four hours they will have to login again and their work will be lost if not saved earlier, then that already solves your problem by setting the session timeout.

If you constantly postback (Ajax or otherwise) to save the current information, then the 4 hour timeout is not needed, you could post back every 5 minutes - which will keep the session alive anyway.

However, if the user must still have their data available to save - even if they don't save it within 4 hours, then the session timeout is irrelevant, it is only there as a security measure.

You could save the form data on the user's postback (if the session has timed out) before redirecting to the login page, then retrieve the saved values and continue as normal after the successful login. This could be intercepted in Application_PostAuthenticateRequest in the global.asax.cs.